# Getting input from form to use in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So, I am pretty new when it comes to messing with JSON, AJAX and that kind of stuff...
I have this one assignment which I am supposed to have 4 input fields: "Start city", "Start state", "Destination city" and "Destination state".
It is basically supposed to get the distance between city A to city B. It was given a file with the information behind that, the thing I need to do is get the inputs, and get the data from the file if that makes sense.

I thought about having a javascript function something like this:

```
function getData()
{
    var xhttpData = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost/cgi-
        bin/ercanbracks/mileage/mileageAjaxJSON";

    xhttpData.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var parseData = this.responseText;
            console.log(parseData);
            var trip = parseData.trip;
            document.getElementsByName("startCity")[0].value =  
                trip.startcity;
            document.getElementsByName("startState")[0].value =  
                trip.startstate;
            document.getElementsByName("endCity")[0].value =  trip.endcity;
            document.getElementsByName("endState")[0].value =  
                trip.endstate;

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  trip.startcity + ", 
                " + trip.startstate + ", " + trip.miles + " miles to " + 
                trip.endcity + ", " + trip.endstate + ".";
        }
    };


    xhttpData.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttpData.send();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { getData(); 
});
```

Here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://localhost/~arthurfig/week11.js"></script>
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" onsubmit="getData()">
            <p>Start City: </p>
            <input type="text" name="startCity">
            <p>Start State: </p>
            <input type="text" name="startState">
            <p>Destination City: </p>
            <input type="text" name="endCity">
            <p>Destination State: </p>
            <input type="text" name="endState">
            <input type="submit" value="Check">
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is what is in the file:

```
{"trip" : 
  { "startcity" : "",
    "startstate" : "",
    "endcity" : "",
    "endstate" : "",
    "miles" : "Unknown"
  }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to get the value of the text fields from the form to set as the value of the variables and make it get the distance(miles) using these values.

Comment: Where's your form? What data and in what format needs to be passed to your `mileageAjaxJSON` service?

Comment: @Arthur Figueiredo You need to get or send the data from/to http://localhost/cgi-bin/ercanbracks/mileage/mileageAjaxJSON ?

Comment: @jNewbie, I need to get data. Phil, I edited the code with more details. I don't. It all has to be query string. Here is part of the command for me to do, " Your “query string” must be appended to this URL. The CGI program returns the mileage data as JSON text". Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, the file I'm supposed to get data from is a c++ program which I don't think I have access to. That's why it's blank in those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getData() {
    var xhttpData = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/ercanbracks/mileage/mileageAjaxJSON";

    xhttpData.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var parseData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var trip = parseData.trip;
            document.getElementsByName("startCity")[0].value =  trip.startcity;
            document.getElementsByName("startState")[0].value =  trip.startstate;
            document.getElementsByName("endCity")[0].value =  trip.endcity;
            document.getElementsByName("endState")[0].value =  trip.endstate;

            var text = trip.startcity + ", " trip.startstate + ", " + trip.miles + " miles to " + trip.endcity + ", " + trip.endstate + ".";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        }
    };


    xhttpData.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttpData.send();
}
```

Comment: Ok. Also, which would be better: use a form and use onsubmit="getData()" or onclick="getData()"?

Comment: With this code, your getting the data from *mileageAjaxJSON* and updating the form's inputs values.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. I put a <p id="demo"></p> right after the form. I tried with onsubmit but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: You can update the input's values after the DOM's is loaded. So you can  use:

 `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  getData();
});`

Comment: It still won't display the data. Is there a way for me to call getData() in a php page maybe? And set that page as action of the form

Comment: Try to run `getData();` from your browser's console to see if is working

Comment: It says, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string".

Comment: Try to replace: `var parseData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` for `var parseData = this.responseText;`

Comment: Done it. No errors on the console anymore, but still won't display anything. I will edit the post and put the whole code, maybe that will make it easier to see.

Comment: Also, try to log the data. Just add  `console.log(parseData);` after `var parseData = this...`

Comment: Now it says,                                                                                                        
    {"trip" : 
      { "startcity" : "",
        "startstate" : "",
        "endcity" : "",
        "endstate" : "",
        "miles" : "Unknown"
      }
    }
    week11.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startcity' of 
    undefined
        at XMLHttpRequest.xhttpData.onreadystatechange (week11.js:11)"

Comment: He's not getting the trip object. Probably is because we removed the parse. Try to change again to `var parseData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`...

Comment: I did that and now there are no error messages. However, it doesn't display the data. It only displays, ", , Unknown miles to , ."

Comment: Yes, this is because as you said, your object is empty! So it's getting only  "Unknown" and empty strings!
 ("Also, the file I'm supposed to get data from is a c++ program which I don't think I have access to. That's why it's blank in those fields")

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getData(){
var city=document.getElementById("startCity").value;
var State=document.getElementById("startState").value;
var endCity=document.getElementById("endCity").value;
var endState=document.getElementById("endState").value;
console.log(city);    
var s=   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = endState;
}
First you get value from form like this or you can serialize the form , then you emebed your logic
```

Comment: You should explain how and why this code solves the question

Comment: this solution only for get value from input text not fully solved answers.next you can compare the value with your file values

Comment: @manojkumar What *fen1x* was trying to suggest you is that edit your answer and include your explanation in it.